# Spring boot: can't login h2 console

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I'm new in h2 DB, and I have searched for this question, but didn't find solution. I want to try to build a tcp server mode with spring boot, and let others connect it using spring boot or python.
It's my properties below:

```
db2.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
db2.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
db2.datasource.username=sa
db2.datasource.password=
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

I can connect to localhost:8080/h2-console, but can't login, it return

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Sep 09 15:08:13 CST 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
Forbidden
```

I am using spring security, but my method configure is empty in dev mode, I have no idea where I should fix...

my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.200</version>
</dependency>
```

and tcp server config:

```
 @Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
    public Server inMemoryH2DatabaseaServer() throws SQLException {
        return Server.createTcpServer(
                "-tcp", "-tcpAllowOthers", "-tcpPort", "9092");
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void initDb() {
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate=new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        String sqlStatements[] = {
                "drop table employees if exists",
                "create table employees(id serial,first_name varchar(255),last_name varchar(255))",
                "insert into employees(first_name, last_name) values('Eugen','Paraschiv')",
                "insert into employees(first_name, last_name) values('Scott','Tiger')"
        };

        Arrays.asList(sqlStatements).forEach(sql -> {
            jdbcTemplate.execute(sql);
        });

    }
```

Does someone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, I found the problem.
It's because I am using spring security, and is auto enable protection of CSRF, so I extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and override `configure`:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
    }
```

and it works successfully.

Comment: This is out of date so I am adding the new version

Answer (score 1):

I think you have included the spring security starter. By default, it will protect all paths, try to exclude the H2 console path(*/h2-console*) in the security config.

Answer (score 1):

For Spring Security 5+ this works

```java
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                .requestMatchers(
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/actuator/**")
                ).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/h2-console/**")
                ).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        );
        http.csrf((csrf) ->
                csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers(
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/h2-console/**")
                ).csrfTokenRepository(
                        CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()
                )
        );
        http.headers((headers) -> headers
                .frameOptions(
                        HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::disable
                )
        );
        return http.build();
    }
```